# Build trigger for Spring Boot application on Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: java, spring, maven, google-app-engine, maven-gae-plugin

I'm attempting to achieve automatic build and deployment on the Google Cloud Platform using build triggers with Google App Engine. The build is currently triggered when I push to the master branch of my linked Github repository.

The application is a Spring Boot application with Maven, which is serving a simple API. I'm trying to issue the `mvn appengine:deploy` in my `cloudbuild.yaml` file, which looks like this:

```
# cloudbuild.yaml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
  args: ['appengine:deploy']
```

The `mvn appengine:deploy` works as expected when I run it in the Google Cloud Shell, but does not work when it is executed by the build trigger.

The triggered build run for about 20 seconds, and then fails with the following error message:

```
Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:deploy failed: The Google Cloud SDK could not be found in the customary locations and no path was provided.
```

This is my `pom.xml` configuration

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example.api</groupId>
  <artifactId>api</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>api</name>
  <description>API</description>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <appengine.maven.plugin>1.3.2</appengine.maven.plugin>
    <jetty-maven-plugin>9.3.7.v20160115</jetty-maven-plugin>
    <gcloud-maven-plugin>2.0.9.121.v20160815</gcloud-maven-plugin>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
         <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
         <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>${appengine.maven.plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
       <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
       <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>${jetty-maven-plugin}</version>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Any ideas what I might be missing in my configuration? I had a hard time finding any examples online of a `cloudbuild.yaml` deploying on the Google App Engine using Maven.

Comment: The cloud shell executes in a server context in which the cloud SDK is available. Is the SDK available in the server context in which the triggered build executes? The error message suggests it *might* not be (or that it or the build might be incorrectly configured).

Answer (score 2):

The `appengine-maven-plugin` [requires](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin#requirements) the Cloud SDK to be installed.
Since the `gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn` docker image does not have it installed, the `appengine:deploy` goal fails.

I can think of two ways of working around this:

1) Create a custom Cloud Build build step (Dockerfile) that has both [maven](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/blob/master/mvn/Dockerfile) and [gcloud](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/blob/master/gcloud/Dockerfile). Then deploy it to your GCR and use it in your `cloudbuild.yaml` instead of `gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn`.

2) Do not use `appengine-maven-plugin`, but split the build and deploy into several steps.

```
# cloudbuild.yaml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
  args: ['package']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy', '/workspace/.../target/path-to-app.yaml']
```

Note that after building the WAR, you might need to use `gcloud` several times to stage the app before calling `gcloud app deploy`.

Comment: Upvoted without having tested it myself but both options make sense and deserve a try.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a similar error message when I upgraded to my new MacBook. I moved the `google-cloud-sdk` folder in the `/usr/local/share/google/` directory i.e. `/usr/local/share/google/google-cloud-sdk` and that solved my issue.